# Xcode 7 Swift 2 error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, SUBCODE=0X0)

Tags: swift, xcode7

Ello! I am working on a notes app for mac, using swift as the language. I am currently working on a save and load feature, and have run across an error I am not sure how to fix. Here is the problematic code:

```
import Cocoa

class NoteViewController: ViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var notefield: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var savenamefield: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var loadnamefield: NSTextField!

    @IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject) {
        // The line below gets the error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(notefield.stringValue, forKey: savenamefield.stringValue)
    }


    @IBAction func load(sender: AnyObject) {
        var name = loadnamefield.stringValue;
        var lnote = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(name)
        notefield.stringValue = lnote as! String
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }

}
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: That's most likely the much-loved *Unexpected found nil...* error. Are the outlets connected in Interface Builder? Second thought: `lnote` is `nil` in the `load` method. By the way, there is a dedicated `stringForKey` method in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: I didn't know about stringforkey. I might try that. Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: It doesn't hurt to read the documentation ;-) There are some secrets to discover...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. With some testing, I discovered that everything worked until I added notefield.stringValue into the code.I then realized that I had this is a different window. The code is covering 3 different windows, 2 of which are popups. notefield is the only element I had inside the code from the main window. I moved all of the elements to the same window, and recoded the entire thing. I got it working well using the following code:

```
import Cocoa

class NoteViewController: ViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var notefield: NSTextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var savenamefield: NSTextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var loadnamefield: NSTextField!

    @IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(notefield.stringValue, forKey: savenamefield.stringValue)
    }

    @IBAction func load(sender: AnyObject) {
        notefield.stringValue = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey((loadnamefield?.stringValue)!) as! String
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }

}
```

Please note that I am supplying this code as a guideline only. Thanks for the help that was given.